# Java: Скачивание файлов с помощью Google Chrome в headless режиме (автоматизация)

Tags: java, google-chrome, test-automation

Доброго времени суток,

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Имеется тест, который

1. Заходит на определённую страницу.
2. Жмет кнопку "скачать".
3. Идет в папку и проверяет наличие файла по заданным критериям.

Все выполняется без проблем, но только пока не включен headless режим.

Проблема заключается в том, что при включении headless режима,
**сам процесс скачивания файла не происходит...**

Я нашел некоторые решения в интернете, которые в принципе были похожи между собой.
После реализации одно из таких workaround, я все равно оказался на том же месте где и был, а точнее процесс скачивания файла так и не начался.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и главное смог ее решить, то прошу вашей помощи.

**Вот пример настроек которые я использую для хром драйвера:**

```
 if (System.getProperty("selenium.grid").equals("true")) {
                ChromeDriver chromeDriver;
                switch (browser) {
                case "chrome":

ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
                        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
                                .setHeadless(true)
                                .addArguments("--test-type")
                                .addArguments("--disable-extensions");
                        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions);
                        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(chromeDriver);

       Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
                        commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("behavior", "allow");
                        params.put("downloadPath", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/");
                        commandParams.put("params", params);
                        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                        String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);

                        String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + chromeDriver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
                        System.out.println("Link = " + u);
                        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
                        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
                        httpClient.execute(request);

                        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, после обновления браузера Google Chrome до версии 72 бета, указанный выше воркараунд, прекрасно заработал в headless режиме.